# Html Http request read source

Tags: html, http, web

When I view a website in my browser (for example https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.725-inch-miter-saw-with-laser.1000748698.html), it contains information that is not in the source code.

For example, the source code of this page doesn't specify a product price:

```
                    <span itemprop="price">-</span>

                    <small>/

                        each</small>
```

However, when viewed in a browser, the tag does actually contain a price.

How can I retrieve the product's price from the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: just by reading the source, you can't. The price is dynamically loaded from their servers (using javascript), after the page loaded.

Using appropriate tools (such as the network tab in Chrome/Firefox's developer console) you can figure out where they retrieve the price from (in this case JSON document on their servers). However, even if you used that, there is no guarantee that it'll still work tomorrow - they can charge their link or the format of the data at any moment.

A good place to get started on the technologies they use is reading up on

- JavaScript
- AJAX
- JSON

If you are interested in retrieving information from their page pro grammatically, a good start would be to contact them to see if they have a public interface (API) you can use. These are usually more stable to use.